# Creating SQL Query involving two tables where one table is required only for a single value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and I'm having trouble figuring out how to create the sort of query I need.

The details are as follows.
I have two tables that I need to retrieve data from. They are **'Client'** and **'Bids'**

The **'Client'** table has the following values that I need to obtain:
*'`ClientId`', '`ClientFirstName`', '`ClientSurName`', '`ClientAddressLine1`', '`ClientAddressLine2`', '`ClientAddressLine3`', '`telephoneHome`', '`telephoneWork`', '`telephoneMobile`', '`clientFax`', '`clientEmail`'*

From the **'Bids'** table, I only need to obtain *'`clientId`'*

My issue is that I need to display in a table a list of ALL clients regardless of if they have a bid associated with them. I also need to display using *'Y'* or *'N'* if they have a bid or not.

I have tried multiple different ways to do this but to no avail.
I can't use UNION because the **'Client'** and **'Bids'** tables contain a different amount of columns and using a JOIN (at least as far as I know how to use it) only displays clients whose *'`clientId`'* corresponds to a *'`clientId`'* in the **'Bids'** table.

As it stands, my sql query looks like this:

```
SELECT Client.*, Bids.clientId AS clientBidId FROM Client JOIN Bids ON Client.clientId = Bids.clientId ORDER BY Client.clientId ASC
```

As previously stated, this doesn't show clients who don't have a bid. It is also duplicating clients for some reason (I suspect this is based on how many bids they have associated with them).

Normally, I'd keep banging my head against the desk until I came up with a solution but I find myself with a limited amount of time and I'm at a complete loss on how to solve this since I'm so new to SQL so I've come here - for the first time - to see if any of you can provide some assistance. Even pointing me in the right direction would be a great help.

Comment: What do you want your output results to look like, if you don't want duplicated clients? You are correct that multiple bids for a client will result in multiple rows returned. To solve the other issue of listing all clients, you simply need `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: See [A visual explanation of SQL joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) (by one of Stack Overflow's founders)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response! And thank you for helping with my JOIN problem, using LEFT JOIN fixed that issue! 
As for the duplicates, I am displaying the data in an HTML table using PHP. I want a single entry for each client in my HTML table and just a 'Y' or 'N' under the heading 'Current Bids?'

Comment: So you don't actually need to return the bid then?

Comment: No, I just need to acknowledge if the client has any bids or not. I have seen that there is a DISTINCT operator in SQL, is there a way this can be applied to just the clientId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what a LEFT JOIN is for; rows without a corresponding row in the secondary table will contain `NULL`.

For the duplication, you can `GROUP` the results `BY clients.id`.  I included a count of bids since it's at least as useful as 'Y'/'N'.

```
SELECT clients.*, count(bids.id) as bids
FROM clients
  LEFT JOIN bids ON bids.client_id = clients.id 
  GROUP BY clients.id;
```

Consider this functionally complete example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0c257/1

Comment: Please copy your query answer here and link to sqlfiddle as a supplement, don't make us go offsite to read the answer.

Comment: (note - you'll probably want a `DISTINCT` on that to reduce one row per client as the OP is requesting)

Comment: fair enough.  Fixing for duplicates and I'll paste the resultant query.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted with the use of the LEFT JOIN and GROUP BY operators.